# The response changes with new calls, but I already have the key from the first response saved

Tags: ansible

I want to check the result of a REST API JSON call. If the response in the JSON `message_ready` key is not zero, I want to retry the call.
The response changes with new calls, but I already have the key from the first response saved.

Ansible tasks

```yaml
- name: test message_ready 
  uri:
    url: http://localhost:15672/api/queues
    method: GET
    return_content: yes
    body_format: json
  register: result

- name:   messages_ready zero 
  debug:
    msg: message_ready "{{ item }}"
  until: item == 0
  loop: "{{ result.json | json_query(jmesquery)}}"
  vars:
    jmesquery: "[*].message_ready" 
  retries: 5
  delay: 10
```

Result from test message_ready

```json
{
    "json": [
        {
            "auto_delete": false,
            "consumer_capacity": 0,
            "consumer_utilisation": 0,
            "consumers": 0,
            "messages_paged_out": 0,
            "messages_persistent": 0,
            "messages_ram": 0,
            "message_ready": 0,
            "messages_unacknowledged": 0,
            "name": "test.v2",
            "state": "running",
            "type": "classic",
            "vhost": "aaa"
        },
        {
            "auto_delete": false,
            "consumer_capacity": 0,
            "consumer_utilisation": 0,
            "consumers": 0,
            "messages_paged_out": 0,
            "messages_persistent": 0,
            "messages_ram": 0,
            "message_ready": 0,
            "messages_unacknowledged": 0,
            "name": "test.v3",
            "state": "running",
            "type": "classic",
            "vhost": "aaa"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: sorry i dont understant what you want? what is your problem?

Comment: The problem is saving the result . 
The result is saved and retrying in messages_ready zero does not work because I don't know that there was a change in test message_ready

Comment: Can you provide a much more detailed description of the problem? And can you provide a minimal reproducible test example? Especially with `result` output and the `message_ready` part?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure this reaches your target as you did not provide an example of the json structure returned by your query. But, in a nutshell:

```yaml
    - name: test message_ready 
      uri:
        url: http://localhost:15672/api/queues
        method: GET
        return_content: yes
        body_format: json
      register: result
      retries: 5
      delay: 10
      until: result.json.message_ready | default('') == 0

    - name: Debug registered var
      debug:
        var: result
```

Comment: Thank but your code return  FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'result.json.messages_ready == 0' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (result.json.messages_ready == 0): 'list object' has no attribute 'messages_ready'"}

Comment: Once again, I don't know what your uri is returning, especially when `message_ready` is not 0. I suspect it does not exists at all in some cases. Try with the edit I just made.

Comment: The value always exists I have attached part of the result 
If I modify the code according to yours it never evaluates the condition correctly

Comment: Your uri returns a list of objects which all contain a `message_ready` item. Which one needs to be equal to 0 for your retries ?